# What is a free pointer in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I learnt that there are two ways of declaring an array in C:

```
int array[] = {1,2,3};
```

and:

```
int* arr = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
```

Why is arr called a free pointer ? And why can't I change the address contained in array while I can do it with array ?

Comment: "*Why is arr called a free pointer*" .. why do you **think** it is? I never heard that before.

Comment: "I learnt that there are two ways of declaring an array in C …" - You learned wrong! Neither is a pointer an array nor an array a pointer.

Comment: Where did you read about the term *free pointer*? If you use `malloc` to obtain a pointer, then certainly later on you do need to *free* the pointer when it's no longer needed (or just exit the program, which also frees it). But I'm not familiar with *free pointer* as a specific, technical term for a kind of pointer. As far as you second question is concerned, I'm not sure what you mean by, *change the address contained in array*. Perhaps you could show an example.

Comment: _And why can't I change the address contained in array while I can do it with array_: you probably meant _And why can't I change the address contained in array while I can do it with **arr**_: because `array` and `arr` are two different things, `arr` is a pointer, and `array` is an array of 3 `ints`s.

Answer (score 5):

As said in comments, you learned something incorrect, from a bad source.

In the second case, `arr` is not an array, it's a pointer. A pointer that (if the allocation succeeds) happens to contain the address of a block of memory that can hold three `int`s, but that's not an array.

This confusion probably comes from the fact that arrays "decay" to pointers in some contexts, but that does not make them equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at how the two objects are laid out in memory:

```
       +---+
array: | 1 | array[0]
       +---+
       | 2 | array[1]
       +---+
       | 3 | array[2]
       +---+

       +---+            +---+
  arr: |   | ---------> | ? | arr[0]
       +---+            +---+
                        | ? | arr[1]
                        +---+
                        | ? | arr[2]
                        +---+
```

So, one immediate difference - there is no `array` object that is separate from the array elements themselves, whereas `arr` *is* a separate object from the array elements.  Only `array` is an *actual array* as far as C is concerned - `arr` is just a pointer to a single object, which *may* be the first element of a sequence of objects or not.

This is why you can assign a new address value to `arr`, but not to `array` - in the second case, there's nothing to assign the new address value *to*.  It's like trying to change the address of a scalar variable - you can't do it, because the operation doesn't make any sense.

It also means that the address of `array[0]` is the same as the address of `array`.  The *expressions* `&array[0]`, `array`, and `&array` will all yield the same address value, although the types of the expressions will be different (`int *`, `int *`, and `int (*)[3]`, respectively).  By contrast, the address of `arr` is *not* the same as the address of `arr[0]`; the expressions `arr` and `&arr[0]` will yield the same value, but `&arr` will not, and its type will be `int **` instead of `int (*)[3]`.